Tampermonkey Script Does not run Anymorre
I wrote a Tampermonkey scripts a year or so ago and noticed recently that it is not doing its job. A bit of debugging and I noted that it did not seem to be running i.e. no logging statements showed up.
So, I made a new script as sinmple as possible:
    // ==UserScript==
    // @name         New Userscript
    // @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
    // @version      2024-11-13
    // @description  description!
    // @author       person
    // @match  https://www.news.com.au/*
    // @icon         data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
    // @grant        none
    // ==/UserScript==

    (function() {
        'use strict';

        console.log('mediaDiv exists');
    })();

This log does not show up.
When the page loads, the extension does confirm that the script is enabled, so I have the match statement correct.
Is the day of this extension over in Chrome? Is it toast?

Someone downvoted my question????

your script works fine on both Chrome and Firefox, the site creates a lot of logs, try filtering for "userscript" or use an alert(1) to make sure the script is running.

Curious. It does not create a single log in my browser - Chrome.

No alert appears when I add the alert.

make sure the script is enabled, or try creating a new script. If it still does not work, update/reinstall tampermonkey

I re-installed the extension and it still does not work. I put an alert in this site to see if the target site was the issue. I suspect one of my other extensions might be interfering with it. I'll try it out on Firefox.

OK. So basic scripting works on Firefox. I must be one of the other extensions in Chrome. I've since lost my original script. Need to write it from scratch LOL

There must be an issue with Chrome. I'm having the same issue. I can't even get an alert to launch. Firefox works fine.
